# Can I cancel installation with inno setup after all files are installed

Tags: inno-setup

I am using inno setup. Is it possible to create custom page after copying all files:

```
Page := CreateCustomPage(wpInstalling, 'expl', 'expl 2');
```

or with other parameters. There is no cancel button. May this page to be able to cancel Installation and revert all files?

Comment: You can run an uninstaller, if the users choses to cancel the installation. Though it's not the same as rollback, particularly, when installing an update. Why don't you ask the user *before* the installation?

Comment: If you want good control on cancellation, then an MSI/MSIX based solution is what you should switch to.